# How to display streaming computation in Google Colab?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I have started learning Pyspark.
So, in a scenario, I was testing if I can use a Gdrive as source for streaming data.
I will put csv file one by one ,and the code will monitor file,and produce aggregation based on that.

Here is my code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,IntegerType,StringType
schema=StructType(
                [
                StructField('File',StringType(),True),
                StructField('Shop',StringType(),True),
                StructField('Sales',IntegerType(),True)
                ]
                )

df=spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header" ,True).option("sep",",").load("/content/drive/My Drive/Pyspark/")
df=df.groupby("shop").sum("sales")
# df.show()



df.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("update").start().awaitTermination()
```

I want to display output of aggregation in colab.
But,its not displaying any output.

Can anyone suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to output the results to a temporary in-memory queryable table where you can better inspect the results.

With console output, besides having problems with notebooks and other terminal buffering output issues, you'll be left to deal with complex text dumps of results that you cannot query, filter, etc.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
query = df \
    .writeStream \ 
    .outputMode("update") \
    .queryName("aggregates") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()
```

Note that I have removed the `awaitTermination()` method so that while the Spark Streaming application is running in the background you can get your notebook cells released to perform analysis in runtime.

Then you can simply query the `aggregates` table like this:

```
spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show(truncate=False)

+-----+------------------+
|shop |sum(sales)        |
+-----+------------------+
|shop1|72312             |
|shop2|92333             |
|shop3|142313            |
|shop4|321123            |
+-----+------------------+
```